# Explaining shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to understand what the following shell script does:

```
echo /cal_abc | sed -e 's/[a-z]*$//'
```

Why it output `/cal_`?  What does `*` and `$`sign mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unfamilier with the `sed` function. Make sure you read some, for example, [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

sed is a **s**tream **ed**itor which is meant to search for patterns inside a string.

The string after it is a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) match to fit the match group from the stream.

In regex:

```
* - Wildcard. can fit any character.
$ - Matches the ending position of the string or the position just before a string-ending newline.
```

Thus, this searches for patterns in /cal_abc which start with any lowercase letter `(a-z)`, any other character `*`, and then a newline or an end.

Examples:

```
"I am a nice str" - > will find 'tr', t+r+end
"I am going to wall st.\nSince I heared you get the best money there" ->st., t+.+newline
"an end is just a new start" - no match for the $ sign.
```

**edit**  the /s - Substitute will replace these with the new prompt, and that's the change you see.

Answer (score 0):

the first s doesn't mean start with s. It's a command of sed. actually first part of sed (in this example s) is the command

$man sed

### s/regexp/replacement/

Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.

### Explain the answer

```
echo /cal_sabc | sed -e 's/[a-z]*$//'
```

1. s   =>   we want to replace
2. what do you want to replace?
   with every string which just contains a-z and it doesn't have any thing else( it doesn't have **_** ) AND ONE ELSE CONDITION: i want it to be in the END of the line ( $ is the end of line)
3. then what to you want to write in the place of that string?
   NOTHING.
4. if you want to write sth instead of it write between two //
   echo /cal_sabc | sed -e 's/[a-z]*$/I MEAN HEAR/'

Comment: Thanks you, editted. For future referance, this kind of things are better off in comments.